# How to return CArray?

Tags: c++, arrays, mfc, return-value, return-type

Which way is good for returning an array of classes?

```
class BigSizeClass {
    int data[1024 * 1024];
};
```

1. Very bad and expensive way:

   ```
   CArray<BigSizeClass> test() {
     CArray<BigSizeClass> ret;
     for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
       BigSizeClass c;
       ret->Add(c);
     }
     return ret;
   }
   ```
2. may be I forget delete returning value:

   ```
   CArray<BigSizeClass>* test() {
     CArray<BigSizeClass>* ret = new CArray<BigSizeClass>();
     for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
       BigSizeClass c;
       ret->Add(c);
     }
     return ret;
   }
   ```
3. may be I do like Expensive:

   ```
   // CArray<BigSizeClass> r = test();  --> Expensive
   // CArray<BigSizeClass>& r = test(); --> Not Expensive (Correct - because of &)

   CArray<BigSizeClass>& test() {
       CArray<BigSizeClass>* ret = new CArray<BigSizeClass>();
       for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
           BigSizeClass c;
           ret->Add(c);
       }
       return *ret;
   }
   ```
4. may be I forget remove objects:

   ```
   CArray<BigSizeClass*> test()
   {
     CArray<BigClassSize> ret;
     for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
     {
       BigSizeClass* c = new BigSizeClass;
       ret->Add(c);
     }
     return ret;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way 1 is just fine. RVO and NRVO will kick in here. Even if it doesn't you can still "swaptimize", assuming that CArray does the smart thing and has a swap function.

```
CArray<BigSizeClass> result;
test().swap(result);
```

However, I'd have to recommend against the use of CArray- it doesn't use the copy constructor but instead uses `memcpy`, which is hideously undefined behaviour for any non-POD classes.

Comment: Do you mean Way0? Because returning value of the way 1 is pointer.

Comment: @Amir: Yes, I do. Why on earth would you index your ways from 0? That's just confusing :(

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you may use R-value references. Unfortunately `CArray` isn't implemented with r-value semantics. You should use STL containers which are R-value/move-semantics aware.

You may, if R-Value can be used, return entire `vector<BigSizeClass>` from the function - vector class would take care of copying (**moving**) the returned vector.